# Google maps AngularJS Ionic grey map intel xdk

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I'm working with Intel XDK and Ionic as framework the problem that i have is i'm trying to use google map and when i load the apk in the emulator and on real device the map display grey and i have to rotate the screen and then the map display as normal with the marker and controllers.

```
<div id="map" style="height: 60vh"></div>
<script>
            var map;
            function initMap() {
              var myLatLng = {lat: -39.83250715421206, lng: -73.23938548564911};

              // Create a map object and specify the DOM element for display.
              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: myLatLng,
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 15
              });

              // Create a marker and set its position.
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: myLatLng,
                title: 'Banco de Sangre'
              });
            }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDl1lpx2C8RmatmhG__vBcmtjEsEPjUVbo&amp;&amp;callback=initMap" async="" defer=""></script>
```

I Try `ionic.Platform.ready(function(){` but then that map load in blank.